# Searching for literature on cognition of flyover animations

Tags: reference-request, vision, visualization, spatial-cognition

I'm rewriting a journal article on flyover animations: the virtual camera moves in a 3D map environment (e.g. a flyover of the Grand Canyon showing off the topography).  The paper describes our user experiment varying characteristics of the flyover and testing its effect on survey knowledge.  Its been peer reviewed and the reviewer pointed out that there is a body of literature on the subject that needs to be synthesised into the paper.  His/her exact words:

> There is literature not covered by the author(s’) review with regards
>   to existing theory and research in:
>
> - spatial cognition and spatial knowledge acquisition;
> - the conceptualization of 3D virtual spaces and 3D camera fly-throughs;
> - empirical geovisualization studies.

What we've already got in the paper relevant to the discussion points:

- Harrower and Sheesley (2007)
- Midtho and Nordvick (2007)
- Thorndyke and HayesRoth (1980)
- Seigal and White (1975)
- Steck and Mallot (1998)

I've done extensive searching using Google Scholar mixing up numerous search terms but I haven't been able to find any further relevant literature.